# How to make my React application automatically make an entry in the database at 00:00 hours (I.E. when its a new day)?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I am using axios in my React App and i have the following code ::-

```
axios.put(`Dates/${ todaysDate.getFullYear() }/${ this.utilMonthInAlpha(todaysDate.getMonth()) }/${ ( todaysDate.getDate() > 9 ) ? todaysDate.getDate() : '0' + todaysDate.getDate() }/.json` , {
        goodHabits : userStoredHabits,
        totalScore : '0'
});
```

The above code is in my `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook , so everytime the user loads the application the above code is executed, in my google firebase database the entry looks like below:

[image: google firebase database]

Now i want the data to be entered for each day of the month irrespective of weather the user accesses my application or not , so how do i go about doing that ? so you can see from the 5th - 9th when the user has not accessed the application the entry is not made, so how do i make my React application automatically make an entry in the database ?

Ideally for example today is the `9th` and its around `7:37 PM` , so as soon as the clock strikes 00:00 and its the 10th i would like my application to automatically make an entry into the database, how do i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**On the server**

If you want your database to be updated while your user is not using your app, you will have to run something on a server to update it.

You could use a Cloud Function that updates your database in response to an hourly Cloud Pub/Sub trigger.

You could store the users' time zones and execute the database updates from the function only when the hourly job is run closest to midnight in the user's time zone.

Setting up cron jobs can be done using the `functions-cron` package. The readme includes instructions on setting up an hourly job.

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/functions-cron

**In the app**

Does it really matter for your app that the database gets updated every day at midnight? Perhaps your app can query the database when it is opened, and check which updates have been missed, and send them all to the database then.